# Is there a transparent way to force 64-bit gcc compilation on Solaris

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, solaris

Is there a way to force '-m64' not overriding CXXFLAGS/CFLAGS. I want automatic x64 build environment like in Linux/BSD amd64.

Why do I need this?

The problem is complexity of the project I need to be buit as x64 on Solaris. It contains several parts and each may use specific C/C++ compiler flags. So, I can't just run:

```
CXXFLAGS=-m64 O2 ...
CFLAGS=-m64 -O2 ...
./configure
```

because there are no common C/C++ flags.

All I need is the way to transparently append '-m64' to every gcc/g++ call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a wrapper (eg: ~/bin/gcc) that would add the required option(s) and put ~/bin first in your PATH. eg:

```
#!/bin/ksh
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64 "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's quite ugly workaround. Actually, I've found the simalar way - I override CC="gcc -m64" and CXX="g++ -m64". It works now. Unfortunately, it seems that such hacks are the only possibility to solve this problem. How reliable is this? Do we need to override LD or something else?

Comment: No more (no less) an ugly workaround than an ugly requirement ...
Anyway, as long as your building scripts/tools do not alter the PATH (resp CC/CXX) variables, the method should be reliable. No need to override LD or anything else.

Comment: Ok then. Since there are no other ways (it seems so at least) I accept your answer. Though, I don't understand why do you think that requirements are ugly.

Comment: Blindingly build everything in 64 bit is questionable. In any case, that's not the way Solaris use to do things.

Comment: Yep. Solaris just proposes nothing at all )) And I described why do I need "blind" compilation. Anyway, something like alternatives on Linux, or gcc_select on Mac OS, or Visual Studio environment scripts (vsvars.bat) would be great I think.

Answer (score 2):

CPPFLAGS is used for the c preprocessor.  It should be picked up by both gcc and g++.

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html