# SQLite Incomplete Type Error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm writing a C++ program that uses SQLite for database. For this line of code;

```
void testRun()
{
    // some code here

    sqlite3_stmt stmt;

    // some code here too
}
```

I get the following error;

```
error: aggregate 'sqlite3_stmt stmt' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     sqlite3_stmt stmt;
                  ^
```

I'm using the amalgamated SQLite source code and have "sqlite3.h" included. What exactly causes this error and how can it be solved?
I'm on Windows 7 64bit, using MinGW_64.

Comment: I never used sqlite directly from the C library, but I suppose that its types aren't meant to be instantiated directly, but instead you have to keep only opaque pointers to them (like you use `FILE *`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978020/compiling-sqlite-for-windows-64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an opaque structure known only to the implementation.  You can't create an instance of it, but you can create a pointer to one:

```
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT...", -1, &stmt, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Any where to learn more about opaque structures/objects?