# Functional test: sqlite does not include soundex()

Tags: php, symfony, sqlite, liipfunctionaltestbundle

Attempts to build a functional test where soundex() is required fail due to the fact that the function by default is not compiled in pdo_sqlite. Functional tests are being built using LiipFunctionalTestBundle.

The error reported is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function:
> Soundex

and the SQLite documentation says:

> The soundex(X) function ... is omitted from SQLite by default

I've tried (from php docs) `$db->sqliteCreateFunction('soundex', 'sqlite_soundex', 1);` where

```
    function sqlite_soundex($string)
    {
        return soundex($string);
    }
```

but get

> ...sqlite_soundex is not callable...

So, how to compile a version of Windows `php_pdo_sqlite.dll`? (SQLite docs show how to compile a "plain" sqlite.dll.)  Or is there a better solution?

#### Edit - with MS Visual Studio 12 Express, compile time option unknown!

```
>cl sqlite3.c  -SQLITE_SOUNDEX  -link -dll -out:php_pdo_sqlite.dll
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-SQLITE_SOUNDEX'
sqlite3.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:sqlite3.exe
-dll
-out:php_pdo_sqlite.dll
sqlite3.obj
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it for Windows? If you are developing in Windows - it is better to install virtual machine and do everything in *nix system. It is much easier to compile php modules there. Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php

Comment: @Cheery: Yeah, I've heard that.  Already have 2 VMs on my windows box for checking my work. I'm just old school.  Besides, that wouldn't solve the problem - pdo_sqlite still won't have soundex().

Comment: `pdo_sqlite still won't have soundex()` but, if you recompile it with https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#soundex Except that you will be dependable on the current install.

Comment: @Cheery: I've been to that page.  My utter lack of experience with compiling does not get me from those instructions to either a php_pdo_sqlite.dll or a pdo_sqlite.so. Can you point me to something that will close the loop?

Comment: It looks like you just need to define SQLITE_SOUNDEX. The command-line syntax for that is `/DSQLITE_SOUNDEX`. So you might try something like `cl sqlite3.c  /DSQLITE_SOUNDEX  -link -dll -out:php_pdo_sqlite.dll`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thank you for this.  Unfortunately, after replacing the original dll I get "PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php_pdo_sqlite.dll'".  So it looks like I'm missing some PHP magic.  I'm working with v5.4.25.

Comment: Read the procedures, answers, and comments for this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10978020/562459

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I'm guessing this will give me the same results as I get trying to compile in my Ubuntu 14 VM.  I have since learned that the more likely successful path is to build from within the php source code and php extension skeleton, etc.  Since that route is less than well documented I'm going to move my development and testing to the Ubuntu VM.  Two reasons: one, pdo_sqlite.so includes `soundex()`; two, running the functional test takes 2/3 the time! But I thank you for your contributions.

Comment: @Cheery Turns out you were right about *nix but for a different reason. As you may read in the above comment, the PHP installed in Ubuntu has a sqlite that includes `soundex()`.  That's where I'm moving to.

Comment: @geoB `compile time option unknown!` it should be something like `-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX`

Comment: @Cheery See my quasi-duplicate post [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548953/compile-sqlite-with-soundex-feature) for syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to add the `soundex()` function to php_pdo_sqlite.dll

The following is an adaptation of the instructions [Build your own PHP on Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).  I used Visual Studio 12 Express for Desktop & PHP 5.5 source code from windows.php.net.

Proceed per instructions up to extracting source code into the tree. At that point I modified `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\php-5.5.18\ext\pdo_sqlite\config.w32`, adding `/D SQLITE_SOUNDEX`

config.w32 snippet

```
// $Id$
// vim:ft=javascript

ARG_WITH("pdo-sqlite", "for pdo_sqlite support", "no");

if (PHP_PDO_SQLITE != "no") {
    EXTENSION("pdo_sqlite", "pdo_sqlite.c sqlite_driver.c sqlite_statement.c", null, "/DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=" + (PHP_ZTS == "yes" ? "1" : "0") + " /D SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 /D SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 /D SQLITE_CORE=1 /D SQLITE_SOUNDEX /I" + configure_module_dirname + "/../sqlite3/libsqlite /I" + configure_module_dirname);
    
    ADD_EXTENSION_DEP('pdo_sqlite', 'pdo');
    // If pdo_sqlite is static, and sqlite3 is also static, then we don't add a second copy of the sqlite3 libs
    if (PHP_PDO_SQLITE_SHARED || PHP_SQLITE3_SHARED || PHP_SQLITE3 == 'no') {
        ADD_SOURCES(configure_module_dirname + "/../sqlite3/libsqlite", "sqlite3.c", "pdo_sqlite");
    }
}
```

Step 14: `configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-pdo --with-pdo-sqlite=shared`

Step 15: `nmake php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

The result was a php_pdo_sqlite.dll in the ...\Release_TS directory

I needed to update my PHP installation from 5.4 to 5.5 and tested.  The original sqlite dll caused the soundex() error.  The replacement dll allowed the test to pass.  **SUCCESS!**

#### EDIT - for PHP 7.0.0

After several failed attempts, changing Step 14 above to `configure --disable-all --enable-pdo --with-pdo-sqlite=shared  --enable-apache2-4handler` allowed creation of a `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` with the `soundex()` function.