# bison.exe not found compiling PHP7 in VS15

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio-2015

Attempting to compile PHP in Windows with Visual Studio 15 (community edition) results in

`Checking for bison.exe ...  <not found>`

All I'm after is a version of php_pdo_sqlite.dll that includes the `soundex()` function.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877299/functional-test-sqlite-does-not-include-soundex) for the PHP 5 method I used.

I do know that VS Code is insufficient, and that installing VS 15 community does not add the path to `cl.exe`.  Because I only need to go through this exercise to get the dll I am grossly unfamiliar with Visual Studio.  Where is `bison.exe`?  [And yes, I know that `soundex()` is in pdo_sqlite in *nix.]

Comment: It's [this Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). It shouldn't be that difficult to locate a Windows version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [this fellow](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm)? It's a parser generator (in case you didn't know) built for windows platform. You'll have to install the binary somewhere in your PATH, so that VS could find it.

Comment: Thanks immensely! It sure had me buffaloed!

Comment: Now all I have to do is find `malloc.h`: `Cannot open include file: 'malloc.h'`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that bison.exe (or the related files) is not on your system. In that case @Dmitry (and others') suggestion is correct.
However, another fix is to launch the Developer Command Prompt in VS15 and be sure to run {rootdir}\bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat before you run configure. This solved my issue.

Comment: "Above?" Better to refer to other questions in a position-independent way. Right now, only the question is above your answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should replace the other one.